# Will a small cut heal faster when "aired" periodically, or should it always be bandaged?

Tags: medical-science

I've been told to take the Band-Aid off a small cut every once in a while in order for it to heal faster.  Is this good advice, or should I try to keep it covered as much as possible?

Comment: I believe that J&J the makers of of the Band-Aid brand suggest that you remove clean the wound and apply a new bandaid at least daily.  I do not know that this is to help it heal faster so much as to help avoid infection.  An infected wound would definatly heal slower though.

Comment: Finding a lot of yahoo answers saying to let it air out, finding lots of news articles saying that [this is a huge mistake](http://www.nytimes.com/2006/08/01/health/01real.html), still looking for something with references though.

Comment: @Chad: I don't mean replace the bandage: I mean taking it off for a while, and then getting a new one to put back on.  I don't know how much the chances of infection goes up by doing this, though.  That's partly what I want to know.

Comment: I would expect that would depend on what you do while your wound is exposed.  If you are in a basically clean environment and prevent contact to it from contaminated  then It should not hurt though I would expect it will not help either.  But your chances of exposing the wound to dangerous bacteria increase the more it is uncovered.  So I would expect that the net is this is going to hinder more often than it would provide any benefit.

Comment: Band aid makers say use them, they have a vested interest in such advice, personally I have never used them since I was a kid and found cuts heal much faster without them, invested my band-aid money in stocks.

Comment: I've heard that this is a plot by Big Pharma to sell more band-aids.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Presumably, you've been told to take the Band-Aid off periodically in order to give it air. In fact, this slows healing, so if you wish to have your cut heal as quickly as possible, **keep it bandaged**.

The primary benefit of a bandage is to help seal the wound and stop or slow bleeding and prevent re-injury and infection. Where people start to differ in opinion is once the wound has been cleaned and placed in a sterile environment. At this point, the primary benefit of bandages are to keep the wound moist, which your well-meaning friend might not realize provides optimal conditions for healing.

> [dressings] are designed to create a moist wound healing environment which allows the wound fluids and growth factors to remain in contact with wound, thus promoting autolytic debridement and accelerating wound healing. [[1](http://bath.pubget.com/paper/21033498)]

Because of this, airing out the wound is counterproductive.

> Exposing a wound to the air so it can breathe is a [mistake], because it creates a dry environment that promotes cell death. [[2](http://www.nytimes.com/2006/08/01/health/01real.html)]

The moist environment has the bonus of sustaining a provisional extra-cellular matrix throughout the healing process, facilitating cell migration and ultimately, epithelialization. This results in less visible scarring once the wound is healed. [[3](http://emedicine.medscape.com/article/1127868-overview)]

[1]  [Update on wound dressings: Indications and best use](http://bath.pubget.com/paper/21033498)

[2]  [NYT Health](http://www.nytimes.com/2006/08/01/health/01real.html)

[3]  [Medscape - Surgical Dressings](http://emedicine.medscape.com/article/1127868-overview)

Comment: Plus, the bandage keeps the wound warm, which also accelerates the healing process. I recently read something about weather opening a bandage for medical inspection is good or bad, which is (in some cases) not clear because the wound cools down which extends the healing for a few hours. (Sorry, I couldn't find the source)

Comment: There are also [Silicone Scar Sheets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silicone_scar_sheet) but apparently the jury is still out on their efficacy. They work by keeping the scar sealed off until it's healed.